# Aerospike Apply a UDF to a Predetermined list of Primary Keys

Tags: aerospike

I have a UDF that updates the TTL of a record. I also have a list of Primary Keys to which I want to apply my UDF. The list is generated outside of Aerospike and is quite large containing at least 25 million keys.

I have successfully run my UDF on:

1. A specific record: 
   `execute functions.updateTTL() on namespace.set where PK = 'some key'`
2. A whole set:`execute functions.updateTTL() on namespace.set`

**How can I apply my UDF to only the records whose keys are contained in my list?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to loop through the keys in your client code and use option 1.

Also, be careful about updating TTL - if you are reducing current remaining TTL of a record to expire it out early, you may be asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I reached the same conclusion. Do you know if there are any good example of this kind of functionality? Why is it asking for trouble?

Comment: If the goal is to force expire or delete the records, use Durable Deletes - if you have Enterprise Edition. (not available in Community Edition). The trouble that will ensue is if a) you are using persistent storage, 2) you restart a node without zeroizing the SSDs, then there are corner cases where these records can come back to life.  The records are written to SSDs in log structured fashion and depending on which version is read first - think a circular buffer practically, the older version may prevail.